# how to copy a class' dict with 2 parameters into 2 lists

Tags: python, list, class

I have a class that contains a list with 2 parameters, I have to save them into 2 lists, modify it and restore the original list from the second ine, if user confirm.
Here's my code:

```
    class Pokemon:
        def __init__(self):
            self.pokemon = {"Poke_Name": "", "Poke_Specie": "", "Poke_Type": "", "Poke_Weight": "", 
            "Poke_Height": "", "Poke_Abilities": [], "Poke_Stats": [], "URL": ""}

        def set_Poke_Name(self, name):
            self.pokemon["Poke_Name"] = name

        def set_Poke_Specie(self, specie):
            self.pokemon["Poke_Specie"] = specie

        def set_Poke_Type(self, tipo):
            self.pokemon["Poke_Type"] = tipo

        def set_Poke_Weight(self, peso):
            self.pokemon["Poke_Weight"] = peso

        def set_Poke_Height(self, altezza):
            self.pokemon["Poke_Height"] = altezza

        def add_Abilities(self, abilita):
            self.pokemon["Poke_Abilities"].append(abilita.poke_abilities)

        def add_Stats(self, stats):
            self.pokemon["Poke_Stats"].append(stats.poke_stats)

        def set_url(self, url):
            self.pokemon["URL"] = url

        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.pokemon)    


    class Poke_Abilities:
        def __init__(self):
            self.poke_abilities = {"Nome": "", "Speciale": ""}

        def set_abilita_nome(self, nome):
            self.poke_abilities["Nome"] = nome

        def set_abilita_speciale(self, speciale):
            self.poke_abilities["Speciale"] = speciale

        def __str__(self):
            return self.poke_abilities
    ...

    nomi = []
    special = []
    for j in pok["Poke_Abilities"]:
        nomi[j] = j["Nome"]
        special[j] = j["Speciale"]
```

This is the error:

```
nomi[j] = j["Nome"]
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

Comment: Pikachu is not copiable. Do you want a copy or deep copy? When you change something in one dict want to reflect changes on other? Define new funcion and return self.pokemon, then can init new Class variable passing that dict as argument and change a bit the init

Comment: What is `pok["Poke_Abilities"]`? The error implies that it's a list of dictionaries, so `j` is a dictionary.

Comment: You can't create new list elements by assigning to an index. You need to use `nomi.append(...)`.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for your help. 
Poke_Abilities is a dictionary, pok is a pokemon class object that contains a list of Poke_Abilites . I need to save all the list in a new one, use it to save chance, and if the user confirm, rewrite the first one from the new one.
how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`j` is a dictionary, you can't use it as a list index in `nome` and `special`. Use `append()` to add them to the lists.

```
for j in pok["Poke_Abilities"]:
    nome.append(j["Nome"])
    special.append(j["Speciale"])
```

Comment: Now I use append() to add them to the list, but i don't know how to copy back right elements from Nome and Speciale in Poke_Abilities at the end

Comment: `for i, n in enumerate(nome): pok['Poke_Abilities'][i].set_Poke_Name(n)`

Comment: Why are you copying these things out of the objects in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Why creating a class with one dict attribute that contains all the others ? Sorry to say that, but this is terrible design and not pythonic.

You should do something like this :

```
class Pokemon:
    def __init__():
        self.name = ""
        self.specie = ""
        self.type = ""
        self.weight = ""
        self.height = 
        self.abilities = []
        self.stats = []
        self.url = ""
```

Same for PokeAbilities.
And that's it. No setter methods. This is no pythonic. You can set an attribute like this :

```
pokemon = Pokemon()
pokemon.name = "Pikachu"
```

Or by adding and passing parameters to the `__init__` function.

And if you need more control when setting attributes, use [properties](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property).

I don't exactly answer to your question but once you do a good design, bugs will disappear.

You have also other options, you can use [namedtuples](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html).